# Compare rows in separate worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare a base row from one sheet with another row from another sheet. The base sheet will always use range A8, B8, C8, and D8. Sheet 2 rows will change dynamically as rows are added or deleted but will always use columns A, B, C, and D. For instance, it may have 3 rows this time and contain 5 rows for the next comparison. However, the comparison will always begin with row 3 in sheet 2 and go until a match is made or run out of rows. If A8 of the base sheet matches A3 of sheet 2 then check B8 of the base sheet with B3 of sheet 2. If A8 does not match A3, move to next row and check A8 with A4 and so on. I am checking if column A of the base row matches column A of sheet 2 (B matches B, C matches C, and D matches D). If the range from the base sheet does not match the range from the other sheet, check the next row for comparison until match = true and return true or else return false. Column A on the base sheet will never match column B, C, or D in sheet 2. B of the base sheet will never match A, C, or D of sheet 2 and so on.

Thanks in advance for your help. Please let me know if you need more information from me.

You are correct. I am looking for a function to return the matching row number or return -1 if no match is found. I liked your idea of concantenating so I am thinking something like this. If I am way off base and there is an easier way to do it, let me know. My pride does not bruise easily.

```
Public Function RangesMatchRow(RefSheet As Worksheet) As Integer
''I need to be able to return matching row number 
Dim Rng, rng2, val As Range
Dim baseStr, refStr As String
Dim lastRow, i As Integer
Dim BaseSheet As Worksheet

Set BaseSheet = Sheets("Base")
'Get the range you want to compare
Set Rng = BaseSheet.Range("A8:D8")
'And concantenate it
For Each val In Rng.Cells
    baseStr = baseStr & val.Value
Next val

lastRow = RefSheet.Range("A").Offset(sheetName.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To lastRow ''It will always start with row three and go until the last row for column A
    rng2 = sheetName.Range("Ai:Di") ''Not sure if this is right but i represents the row number
    For Each val In rng2
        refStr = refStr & val.Value
    Next val
    If StrComp(UCase(baseStr), UCase(refStr), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ''If they match Then
        RangesMatchRow = i ''Set RangesMatchRow equal to i
        Return ''And return
    End If
Next
    RangesMatchRow = -1 ''If no matches are found then return -1

End Function
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Questions without code but with dense requirements are never very interesting ;-)

Comment: This is what I figured out. If no one comes up with a better answer I will add it to the answers section for others looking to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function RangesMatchRow(textInColA As String) As Integer
Dim rng, rng2, val As Range
Dim baseStr, refStr As String
Dim lastRow, i As Integer
Dim sheetName, baseSheet As Worksheet

Set sheetName = Sheets(textInColA)
Set baseSheet = Sheets("Base")
'Get the base range you want to compare
Set rng = baseSheet.Range("A8:D8")
'And concantenate it
For Each val In rng.Cells
    baseStr = baseStr & val.Value
Next val

lastRow = sheetName.Range("A1").Offset(sheetName.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
''Gives me the last row anything was entered in column A
For i = 3 To lastRow
    Set rng2 = sheetName.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i)
    ''Concantenate reference row each time through the loop
    For Each val In rng2.Cells
        refStr = refStr & val.Value
    Next val
    ''Convert everything to uppercase to make it case insensitive
    ''Compare the rows and return the row number if there is a match
    If StrComp(UCase(baseStr), UCase(refStr), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        RangesMatchRow = i
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
    ''Return -1 if no matches are found
    RangesMatchRow = -1

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need a function? Here's the code:

```
Function FIND_PLUS(lookup_value As Range, reference As Range) As Boolean

Dim rng, val, rng2  As Range
Dim str_2_match, formula As String
Dim row_count, i As Double
Dim search_fld() As Variant

Set rng = lookup_value
'first get the string to look for.
'here we concatenated all the values instead of comparing cell by cell
For Each val In rng.Cells
    str_2_match = str_2_match & val.Value
Next val

row_count = reference.Rows.Count
ReDim search_fld(1 To row_count) 'resize the array

'here we made an array of the concatenated values of the range you want to search
'we used simple resize and offset to go through all the rows of your selected range
For i = 1 To row_count
    Set rng2 = reference.Resize(1).Offset(i - 1)
    For Each val In rng2.Cells
        search_fld(i) = search_fld(i) & val.Value
    Next val
Next i
'here is where we performn the actual look up
With Application

Select Case IsError(.Match(str_2_match, search_fld, 0))
Case False
    FIND_PLUS = True
Case Else
    FIND_PLUS = False
End Select

End With

End Function
```

How to use? Paste the code in a module.
You can now use the UDF 'FIND_PLUS'.
In any cell use the formula.
First argument is the range you want to search (in your case it's Sheet1!A8:D8)
Second argument is the range you want search for a match. (Sheet2!A3:D?)
In the cell you typed in the formula will return `TRUE` if there's a match
`FALSE` otherwise.

If in case you don't need a function, this will get you started at least.
I've put comments on specific lines to guide you what the code does.

Comment: The concantenation idea is what did it for me. If I would have thought of that I would not have had to ask for the help in the first place. Thanks. I do not have enough reputation to +1 one your answer but I think it would have worked if I just needed to find out if there was a match without having to return a row number.